# Laravel 5 updating user record with out password

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Essentially I have a page where I can update user records.

```
        {!! Form::label('username', 'Username:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('username', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}

        {!! Form::label('password', 'Password:') !!}
        {!! Form::password('password',['class'=>'form-control'])!!}

        {!! Form::label('name', 'Name:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}

        {!! Form::label('email', 'Email:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('email', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
```

Now there are 2 problems I am facing:

1) If I do not want to change the users password and just edit the name for example, it will update the users password to be empty (or ""). This will be because the text box is empty upon submission.

This is what I have tried in my controller with no joy

```
public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    $newPassword = $request->only('password');

    if(empty($newPassword)){
        $user->update($request->except('password'));
    }else{
        $user->update($request->all());
    }
    return redirect('users');
}
```

Does anyone know how I can tackle this? I'm hopping laravel has a way to deal with these things.

For reference it is laravel 5 that I am using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use: `$request->get('password');`

instead of: `$request->only('password');`

**Why:**

`$request->only();` - returns array with listed fields

In this case it returns array with only one key and empty value, but array isn't empty.

Comment: Thanks this helped me. I am new to laravel so there will always be little tiny things i miss out at the beginning. Thanks!